# UI getting set repeatedly - Data binding, MVVM, Navigation Components

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-architecture-navigation

I am using databinding and MVVM in my current project. Here's the code to one of the screens I am working on :

```
class ActivePlansFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var savingPlanViewModel: SavingPlanViewModel
    private var isFinancialFreedomPlanOpted = false

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        printLog("On Create View")
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_active_plans, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        savingPlanViewModel = activityViewModels {
            printLog("Setting Adapter For Active plans")
            rvAllPlans.apply {
                adapter = ActivePlansAdapter().apply {
                    mBaseAdapterClickListener = { view, position, item ->
                        if( view.id == R.id.tvAction ) {
                            if( isCurrentDestination(R.id.savingPlanListFragment) ) {
                                selectedNeoSavingPlan = item
                                findNavController().navigate(SavingPlanListFragmentDirections.actionSavingPlanListFragmentToAddFundsFragment())
                            }
                        } else {
                            if( isCurrentDestination(R.id.savingPlanListFragment) ) {
                                selectedNeoSavingPlan = item
                                findNavController().navigate(SavingPlanListFragmentDirections.actionSavingPlanListFragmentToSavingPlanDetailsFragment())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    onEmptyOrNot = { isEmpty ->
                        emptyPlansLayout.changeVisibility(isEmpty)
                    }
                    //Update : getAllSavingPlan()
                    observe(allSavingPlanResponsesMutableLiveData) {
                        it?.onChanged { inProgress, failure, list ->
                            //fabCreatePlan.isEnabled = !inProgress
                            planRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = inProgress
                            if (!inProgress)
                                if (failure != null) {
                                    handleFailures(failure) { getAllSavingPlan() }
                                    allSavingPlanResponsesMutableLiveData.clearValue()
                                } else if (list != null) {
                                    removeAll()
                                    val filteredList = list.filter { plan ->
                                        plan.active
                                                || plan.status == NeoSavingPlanResponse.COMPLETED
                                                || plan.status == NeoSavingPlanResponse.CREATE_INITIATED
                                                || plan.status == NeoSavingPlanResponse.DELETE_INITIATED
                                    }
                                    addAll(filteredList)
                                    isFinancialFreedomPlanOpted = list.find { plan -> plan.planType == NeoMasterSavingPlan.FINANCIAL_FREEDOM_PLAN } != null
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            planRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
                getAllSavingPlan()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is the adapter and the rest of the logic is getting set all over again when I navigate back to the screen. I am looking for some help in terms of where to set the UI logic so as to avoid resetting the UI.

```
> Logcat logs :    
>
> D/ActivePlansFragment: On Create View 
> D/ActivePlansFragment: Setting Adapter For Active plans 
> D/ActivePlansFragment: On Create View 
> D/ActivePlansFragment: Setting Adapter For Active plans
```

Update : I moved the plan fetch logic to onResume, that handled the flicker of UI. But the adapter is set again when user comes back to the screen. This has to do with the fragment lifecycle so I am thinking there is no way around this. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        savingPlanViewModel.getAllSavingPlan()
 }
```

Additional Note : I am using android navigation components.

The fragment itself is a part of a parent fragment with viewpager in its xml. The viewpager is a host to active / inactive plans child fragments. The parent class view pager has the offscreen page limit set to 2.

```
savingPlanViewPager.adapter = SavingPlanViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
savingPlanViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
savingPlanTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(savingPlanViewPager)
```

Comment: Do you mean that the "On Create View" is called again on "navigate back"? And what do you mean by  "navigate back"? You have some activity on top and press back or you hame some fragment transactions?

Comment: Fragment to fragment navigation, I am using Navigation components.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't know how Navigation components work, but the code above is not your problem. If onCreateView is called, it means that the Fragment is recreated every time. So look at the code responsible for the Fragment. You are doing something wrong with Navigation components

Comment: The fragment in the above code is part of a parent fragment hosting 2 separate fragments in a view pager. The offscreen page limit has been set to 2. Does it give any hints? @YavorMitev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using lazy initialisation to set the adapter only once. Here's the solution in case someone is looking for it :

```
class ActivePlansFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var savingPlanViewModel: SavingPlanViewModel
    private var isFinancialFreedomPlanOpted = false
    private val navController : NavController by lazy { findNavController() }

    private val adapterClickListener : ((view : View, position : Int, item : NeoSavingPlanResponse) -> Unit) = { view, _, item ->
        if( view.id == R.id.tvAction ) {
            if( isCurrentDestination(R.id.savingPlanListFragment) ) {
                savingPlanViewModel.selectedNeoSavingPlan = item
                navController.navigate(SavingPlanListFragmentDirections.actionSavingPlanListFragmentToAddFundsFragment())
            }
        } else {
            if( isCurrentDestination(R.id.savingPlanListFragment) ) {
                savingPlanViewModel.selectedNeoSavingPlan = item
                navController.navigate(SavingPlanListFragmentDirections.actionSavingPlanListFragmentToSavingPlanDetailsFragment())
            }
        }
    }

    private val onEmptyAdapterListener : ((isEmpty: Boolean) -> Unit) = {
            isEmpty -> emptyPlansLayout.changeVisibility(isEmpty)
    }

    private val activePlansAdapter: ActivePlansAdapter by lazy {
        ActivePlansAdapter().apply {
            mBaseAdapterClickListener = adapterClickListener
            onEmptyOrNot = onEmptyAdapterListener
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_active_plans, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        savingPlanViewModel = activityViewModels {
            getAllSavingPlan()
        }
        rvAllPlans.apply { adapter = activePlansAdapter }
        planRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener { savingPlanViewModel.getAllSavingPlan() }
        setupObserver()
    }

    private fun setupObserver() {
        savingPlanViewModel.apply {
            observe(allSavingPlanResponsesMutableLiveData) {
                it?.onChanged { inProgress, failure, list ->
                    planRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = inProgress
                    if (!inProgress)
                        if (failure != null) {
                            handleFailures(failure) { savingPlanViewModel.getAllSavingPlan() }
                            allSavingPlanResponsesMutableLiveData.clearValue()
                        } else if (list != null) {
                            activePlansAdapter.removeAll()
                            val filteredList = list.filter { plan ->
                                plan.active
                                        || plan.status == NeoSavingPlanResponse.COMPLETED
                                        || plan.status == NeoSavingPlanResponse.CREATE_INITIATED
                                        || plan.status == NeoSavingPlanResponse.DELETE_INITIATED
                            }
                            activePlansAdapter.addAll(filteredList)
                            isFinancialFreedomPlanOpted = list.find {
                                    plan -> plan.planType == NeoMasterSavingPlan.FINANCIAL_FREEDOM_PLAN
                            } != null
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The onCreateView is bound to trigger over and over again, however, we can control the adapter and data initialisation via lazy as illustrated in the above code.